# AngularJS Databinding within pre tags

Tags: html, angularjs, data-binding

I'm simply trying to write out a snippet of code showing how a specific instance of databinding works, but it keeps evluating within the `pre` tag! Even if use { and } it still evalutes. I'm laughing posting this question because it seems so simple but I haven't been able to find a simple answer online. I really don't want to have to create multiple ng-apps just to exclude this one snippet of code.

Code looks like this (I'm using prism):

**pre-escaped**

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter a hex color" ng-model="myColor">
<p style="color: #{{myColor}};">I am color #{{myColor}}</p>
```

**post-escaped**

```
<pre><code class="language-markup">
    &lt;input type=&quot;text&quot; placeholder=&quot;Enter a hex color&quot; ng-model=&quot;myColor&quot;&gt;<br/>
    &lt;p style=&quot;color: #{{myColor}};&quot;&gt;I am color #&#123;&#123;myColor&#125;&#125;&lt;/p&gt;
</code></pre>
```

{{myColor}} also does not work. I simply don't want that thing to evaluate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here ya go:

```
<code ng-non-bindable>{{myColor}}</code>
```

from [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngNonBindable)

Answer (score 1):

try this way

```
ng-bind-html-unsafe="myColor"
```

Sample demo : http://jsfiddle.net/afSsf/1/

Comment: Starting from version 1.2, `ng-bind-html-unsafe` is replaced by `ng-bind-html`. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml